# Still getting error empty array

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm still getting an error in tableView and I can't figure out why:

```
@objc class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var productsToDisplay: [SKProduct]!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // an assync call to load products to the productsToDisplay
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PurchaseItemTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? PurchaseItemTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("Coulnd't parse table cell!")
    }

    // here the app always show an error without any specification
    if(!(self.productsToDisplay != nil && self.productsToDisplay!.count > 0))     {
        return cell
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = "my text"

   return cell

}

}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Or how to fix the error / not load content of the table until data are loaded?

Thank you very much

Comment: you are not returning anything if it is nil.  Use the numberOfRows in section tableview delegate method and return productsToDisplay.count.

Comment: sorry, it in there, I just didn't copy it

Comment: @David To be safe, you should return `productsToDisplay?.count ?? 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically never never never declare a data source array as (implicit unwrapped) optional. Declare it as non-optional empty array:

```
var productsToDisplay = [SKProduct]()
```

The benefit is a non-optional type cannot crash.

---

In `numbersOfRows` return the number of items:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return productsToDisplay.count
  }
```

If the array is empty `cellForRow` is never called.

---

In `cellForRow` first set the label then return the cell and checking for 0 and `nil` is not needed:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PurchaseItemTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PurchaseItemTableViewCell
    let product = productsToDisplay[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = product.name // change that to the real property in SKProduct
    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` should not be called by the system until your async loading call completes.

You have to implement `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` and let it return the number of elements in `productsToDisplay`. Then the systen will call `cellForRowAt indexPath` only if you have at least one row to display.

Remember to call `reloadData` on the `tableView` when your async request is completed.